# How to split the images and annotations into train, test and validation sets for an object detection task?

Tags: python, object-detection

I know that similar threads exists, but I have not been able to find the appropriate answer.

I have seen solutions for the cases where the images are stored based on certain classes, but this is not what I am looking for. I would like to know how to properly split the image dataset into train, test and validation sets, where each image has a corresponding annotation (labeling) file.

The images and their respective annotations(pascal voc/yolo darkent formats) exist both in the same and different directories, depending on the convenience of splitting.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

I think this might be the fastest solution: This later can be applied for obtaining the validation as well.

```
train_size = int(0.8 * len(full_dataset))
test_size = len(full_dataset) - train_size
train_dataset, test_dataset = torch.utils.data.random_split(full_dataset, [train_size, test_size])
```

or let's say:

```
train, val, test = torch.utils.data.random_split(dataset, [1000, 100, 100])
```

given there are 1200 total images.

Comment: scikit learn has something that might be of use: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.KFold.html

Answer (score 0):

Import the train_test_split from sklearn as

`from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split`

You can use

`X_train_confirmed, X_test_confirmed, y_train_confirmed, y_test_confirmed = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.3, shuffle=False)`

0.3 means 30 % data will be test and 70% will be train data

If want to split data w.r.t an equal percentage of target use following

`train_dataset, val_set = train_test_split(data, test_size=0.3, stratify=data.targets)`

here `stratify=data.targets` means it will divide the data equally considering the target i.e. equal portion for each target

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I can assure you that

http://scikit.ml/stratification.html which is

`from skmultilearn.model_selection import iterative_train_test_split`

worked for me for an unbiased and good per class ratio split for the object detection task.

I will write a medium article and gist on it. In the meantime go forward with the link.